# Unable to start or read suphle session

Tags: php

Some background: I'm using a php framework called Suphle, attempting to work with objects wrapping the session superglobal. I have 2 objects: an in-memory copy that I used to test the framework, and I live version interacting with actual cookies and browser stuff, superglobal, etc

All is well with the former. The problem is that the latter selectively captures or resumes session. It worked on one sample application I built previously but is completely broken here. Basically, it cannot lift the csrf token placed into it, nor the origin url. Which means it can't redirect on validation failure. I can't tell whether it's as a result of headers sent, but I'm shamefully at a loss regarding how to debug this because Session troubles should be basic stuff. Now the application is frozen

Here is a link to the browser session class https://github.com/nmeri17/suphle/blob/85cc4f37c6f5e023d163fff3c955b2af4ad669f7/src/Adapters/Session/NativeSession.php#L25. If you need to run the project to trace the root of the problem from an actual browser, you can check this repo https://github.com/nmeri17/xm-assessment/tree/master. If session works, the form should submit. Any other error should be shown (eg missing api key), but the session read call will stop drawing blanks